# Integrate Solr-5.2.1 with crawled data from Nutch?

Tags: solr, nutch

Tutorial says:

> Nutch already created crawl data from the seed URL(s). Below are the steps to delegate searching to Solr for links to be searchable:
>
> Backup the original Solr example `schema.xml`:

```
mv ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml.org
```

But the problem is there is no such directory like `/example/solr/collection1/conf`.

In which directory I will find this `schema.xml` file? Or which `schema.xml` file to replace?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Solr 5.x uses managed-schema in default which will be created on the fly based on the input documents. However you can copy your schema.xml file content to the `${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/solr/server/solr/$CORE_NAME/conf/managed-schema`. But before copy your schema make sure that it is in 5.x schema format. (Some of the old schema components might have changed)